# Any difference between a reboot vs. shutdown/restart on AIX?

Tags: aix, reboot, last

Is a reboot functionally different than performing a shutdown/restart on AIX servers? If they are the same, why are the timestamps different between the 'last system boot' and 'last reboot'?

```
$ who -b  
.        system boot Mar 12 22:15  
$ last reboot  
wtmp begins       Apr 03 23:20
```